# Enter presence and assign marks for multiple students at once

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm building a teacher register web application with Drupal 7 for our school. I have a Chair entity, which references the Class entity and the Teacher role. The Chair entity references also a taxonomy vocabulary to select the available Mark types for that subject (written, oral, practical and graphical, or any combination). I've also created the Lecture entity, which references the Chair entity and allows the Teacher to note the day, the time and the argument of a particular lesson.

Now the hard part: I would like to have a list of students, possibly in the same page of the Lecture entity, where I could note who was absent and the marks the student(s) got during that lesson. The presence will probably be just a numerical field, the Mark is an entity type with a reference to the available Mark types for that Chair and the mark value.

I already looked for a lot of modules to create multiple nodes, but I didn't found anything that would fit my use case. I'm interested in having a table, in each row a student of that class and next to the student the fields of the Mark entity. If the fields will be populated, the new Mark entities for that students will be created, if the fields will remain empty the Mark entities won't be created. Same thing for the absence.

If this isn't possible I'll fall back to something simpler, but this setup would allow teachers to fill marks and absences more quickly (and spare me some rants :) )

Thank you!

Comment: The two modules that will get you close are: [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews), and [Views Megarow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_megarow) as it is used in commerce backoffice.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but unfortunately I need to create new nodes in the students list. I was hoping that this was possible with Views Megarow, but this issue clarifies that it's not: https://www.drupal.org/node/2164505

Comment: I have Eventually decided to a simpler approach: EVA for attaching a view of Marks and one of Absences to the Lecture entity with a link to add a Mark/Absence to the Lecture. Thanks anyway!